# Can this lambda expression become more simple?

Tags: c#, lambda

```
var MaleCount = students.Where(Std => Std.Gender.ToUpper() == "M").Count();
var FemaleCount = students.Where(Std => Std.Gender.ToUpper() == "F").Count();

//List for storing top students records           
List<StudentEntity> TopStudents = new List<StudentEntity>();

//Adding records to List
if (MaleCount > 0)
{
    var maxMarksM = students.Where(o => o.Gender.ToUpper() == "M").Max(o => o.Marks);
    TopStudents = students.Where(o => o.Gender.ToUpper() == "M" && o.Marks == maxMarksM).ToList();
}
if (FemaleCount > 0)
{
    var maxMarksF = students.Where(o => o.Gender.ToUpper() == "F").Max(o => o.Marks);
    TopStudents.AddRange(students.Where(o => o.Gender.ToUpper() == "F" && o.Marks == maxMarksF).ToList());
}

return TopStudents;
```

Comment: At least you can to not use Count... (MaleCount and FemaleCount)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I program in Groovy, but that should not make a difference in this case.

If you don't want to use the chained `.GroupBy().Where()...` solution maybe that way:

Split `students` into `maleStudents` and `femaleStudents` (using `Where()`).

This should remove the need for the if-wrappers and for `Count()` around the lines for male and female students.

So my alternative should look like this:

```
var MaleStudents = students.Where(Std => Std.Gender.ToUpper() == "M");
var FemaleStudents = students.Where(Std => Std.Gender.ToUpper() == "F");

//List for storing top students records           
List<StudentEntity> TopStudents = new List<StudentEntity>();

//Adding records to List
var maxMarksM = MaleStudents.Max(o => o.Marks);
TopStudents = MaleStudents.Where(o => o.Marks == maxMarksM).ToList();

var maxMarksF = FemaleStudents.Max(o => o.Marks);
TopStudents.AddRange(FemaleStudents.Where(o => o.Marks == maxMarksF).ToList());

return TopStudents;
```

Comment: I think than the last '.ToList()' is not necessary.

Comment: And I think that after the first two 'Where' it is prefered write '.ToList()'.

Comment: And most importantly, that 'Max()' will fail if MaleStudents is empty.

Comment: As I said, I program in Groovy, not in C# :-) Crux is I would prefer the LINQ(?) version, but understand that some prefer the more imperative way. So I tried to build a bridge.

Answer (score 6):

```
var topStudents = allStudents
                .GroupBy(s => s.Gender.ToUpper()) // Dividing the students to groups by gender
                .Where(g => g.Key == "M" || g.Key == "F") // Including only the Male and Female genders
                .Select(g => g.Where(s => s.Marks == g.Max(i => i.Marks))) // From each group, finding the highest mark and selecting from that groups all the student with that mark
                .SelectMany(s => s) // selecting all the students from all the inner groups
                .ToList();
```

Edit:

@Alexey Subbota suggested that g.Max might get called too many times, in fact it will be called one time for every student inside the group, which is unnecessary, we only need to compute the maximum once for every group.
If it's an issue, you could do this:

```
var topStudents = allStudents
                .GroupBy(s => s.Gender.ToUpper()) // Dividing the students to groups by gender
                .Where(g => g.Key == "M" || g.Key == "F") // Including only the Male and Female genders
                .Select(g => new KeyValuePair<int, IEnumerable<Student>>(g.Max(s => s.Marks), g)) // Storing the group together with it's highest score value
                .Select(g => g.Value.Where(s => s.Marks == g.Key)) // From each group, selecting the student that have the highest score
                .SelectMany(s => s) // selecting all the students from all the inner groups
                .ToList();
```

Comment: Good answer, but as for me, it's hard to call it "simpler" ^_^

Comment: I am afraid that g.Max(i => i.Marks) will be called too many times

Comment: @AlexeySubbota, yes, you're right. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Spawn Maybe it's a bit harder to grasp if you hadn't done "functional programming" a lot but in terms of size it's a lot shorter, it's also a lot more open to modifications, you could easily extend it to have more groups, you could easily add more filters to the query and you could even make it multi-threaded and parallel with no effort at all (by using the AsParallel method). Linq is a very powerful tool, and i believe that once you learn how to use it properly, it's hard to go back.